# Insert data to jquery table

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I've created a table row using jquery, and I want to fill some data to it. When I was checking with `console.log` the data was appropriate, but not filled the column.

How can I fill the column from it ?

```
function getCorporateService(id){
//create new row
    $br = "<tr id='item'>";
    $br += "<td> <input class='input-small' type='text' id='order_identifier' name='order_identifier' readonly></td>";
    $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='service["+id+"]' name='service["+id+"]' readonly></td>";
    $br += "<td><select id='order_type["+id+"]' name='order_type["+id+"]'> <option> - </option> <option value='add'>Add</option> <option value='change'>Change</option> <option value='cancel'>Cancel</option> </select></td>";
    $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='select_plan["+id+"]' name='select_plan["+id+"]'></td>";
    $br += "<td><input class='input-mini' type='text' id='qty["+id+"]' name='qty["+id+"]'></td>";
    $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='unit_price["+id+"]' name='unit_price["+id+"]'></td>";
    $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='total_price["+id+"]' name='total_price["+id+"]'></td>";
    $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='notes["+id+"]' name='notes["+id+"]'></td>";
    $br += "</tr>";

    $(".corporatesvc").append($br);

    //get data and parsing to column
    $.get("{{ url('salesorder/service')}}/"+id, function(data){
        console.log(id);
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (index, element){
            $('#service['+id+']').val(element.service_name);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following coding is working properly.
if the javascript changed to

```
$('#service\\['+id+'\\]').first().val(element.service_name);
```